# Pergola Span and Support Modification

Tags: structural-engineering

I purchased a [pergola kit](https://newenglandarbors.com/products/12-x-16-barcelona/) and realized afterwords I'm not happy with the placement of the center post.  If possible I'd like to eliminate it.  After searching for a while I haven't been able to find any information regarding span lengths for such a small load.  The inside dimensions of the sleeve surrounding the  horizontal 16' span is 1 3/4 x 5 7/8.  Can anyone help point me in the right direction or recommend a solution?

Comment: I would look for a box section. This one is susceptible to twist in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the two 8ft beams on front and replace them with a 3-1/8 by 6 inch Glulam by 16ft long.

It is close enough in size after paint and strong enough. if your posts are vinyl you need to change them to Doug Fir 4x4 posts.

Comment: Thank you Kamran for your response and time. In the first post I left out a few details ...  The posts are 4x4 and the "sleeve" appears to be ABS.  The horizontal supports are 2 x 6 with an ABS "sleeve".  If possible, I'd like to keep the size consistent all the way around (i.e.  1 3/4 x 5 7/8).  I understand this may not be possible.  I have a couple metal supply houses not too far from me.  What are your thoughts on using aluminum or steel channel instead? Will it be too prone to twist?

Thanks again for taking time to help; I really appreciate your expertise.

Comment: I am not sure you're going to have better selection of sizes with metal lightweight tubing. Anything with thickness of >1/8 inch should do. It's detailing the connections if you use metal. You need to find proper column caps with a wide saddle.

Comment: I was looking at this: https://www.metalsdepot.com/aluminum-products/aluminum-channel-6061      or   https://www.metalsdepot.com/aluminum-products/aluminum-rectangle-tube